# How to create a multi-level sortable portfolio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create a portfolio that can not only sort by different categories but also group the in separate containers, depending on the type of sorting applied. The idea is to do exactly as it is on http://www.big.dk/#projects.

I tried different jQuery plugins like MixItUp and Quicksand but couldn't manage to apply the grouping of elements.

Comment: +1 because MixItUp is absolutely beautiful, never seen it before. Try including some code from what you tried with MixItUp and Quicksand.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look @ http://isotope.metafizzy.co/, you might have to look into http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html as well to create your desired effect i.e. you can filter elements depending on their data-filter attribute and add them to a separate container.